# jQuery .scroll and scrollTop not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

[codepen link](http://codepen.io/themirobin/pen/meLweV)

The scroll event behavior not working in IE properly. When I scroll with mouse wheel down, Header should be fixed at the top with class of `nav-down` but it attach the class `nav-up` first then `nav down`

Other browser working perfectly. 
Can anyone please help me. :)

```
$(function(){
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 600) {
      console.log('WORKING');
          //scroll
          var st = $(this).scrollTop();
          console.log('lastScrollTop:' +lastScrollTop+ 'st: '+st+' position:'+ (lastScrollTop - st));
          if(lastScrollTop - st < 0){
            console.log('down');
            $(".top-header").removeClass("nav-down").addClass("nav-up");
          }else{
            console.log('up');
            $(".top-header").removeClass("nav-up").addClass("nav-down");
          }
          lastScrollTop = st;    
    } else {
       $(".top-header").removeClass("nav-down").addClass("nav-up");
    }
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<header class="top-header nav-up">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"><a class="brand-name">logo</a></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
        <div class="btn btn-header">Download</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="bring-scroll">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <h1>keep scrolling to see the effect of navigation scrolling</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  height: 1600px;
}
.brand-name {
  width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
}
.brand-name img {
  width: 100%;
}
.top-header {
  background: #374965;
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 33;
  padding: 9px 0;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}
.top-header.nav-up {
  top: -60px;
}
.top-header.nav-down {
  top: 0px;
}
.btn-header {
  background: #ec4a3d;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.bring-scroll {
  color: white;
  height: 600px;
  display: block;
  background: #ec4a3d;
  margin-bottom: 5000px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. Hint: Show code here.  There is a snippet editor here too. Also look in the console for errors and report them after googling them

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have edited the post.

Comment: In Chrome, I do not se the header unless I start scrolling up again

Comment: yes exactly same-thing I want in IE but it's not working like chrome

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jQuery are you using? Version 2.X and 3.X only support IE 9+ and it does not support older browser versions, such as IE 6-8, and that could be your case.

This is specified on http://jquery.com/browser-support/

> If you need to support older browsers like Internet Explorer 6-8, Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.12.